# Android app gives "JVMTI error: 103(JVMTI_ERROR_ILLEGAL_ARGUMENT) " when Profiler starts

Tags: java, android, android-studio

In my Android app when I try to start the Profiler it gives me this error and the app crashes shortly afterwards. This is the log:

```
V/StudioProfiler: Profiler initialization complete on agent.
V/StudioProfiler: Handling agent command 405 for pid: 5317.
V/StudioProfiler: Handling agent command 404 for pid: 5317.
V/StudioProfiler: Loaded classes: 15997
V/StudioProfiler: New JNI table set
I/app           : The stack is not large enough for a start_depth of 0.
E/StudioProfiler: JVMTI error: 103(JVMTI_ERROR_ILLEGAL_ARGUMENT) 
V/StudioProfiler: Tracking initialization took: 507444270ns
I/app           : The stack is not large enough for a start_depth of 0.
E/StudioProfiler: JVMTI error: 103(JVMTI_ERROR_ILLEGAL_ARGUMENT) 
I/app           : The stack is not large enough for a start_depth of 0.
E/StudioProfiler: JVMTI error: 103(JVMTI_ERROR_ILLEGAL_ARGUMENT) 
I/app           : The stack is not large enough for a start_depth of 0.
E/StudioProfiler: JVMTI error: 103(JVMTI_ERROR_ILLEGAL_ARGUMENT) 
I/app           : The stack is not large enough for a start_depth of 0.
E/StudioProfiler: JVMTI error: 103(JVMTI_ERROR_ILLEGAL_ARGUMENT) 
W/app           : Verification of void com.android.tools.profiler.support.ProfilerService.<init>(boolean) took 265.237ms
```

I remember that the profiler was working some time ago and I made a lot of changes so I'm not sure why it's not working anymore.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm having the same problem, have you tried running on beta/preview versions of Android Studio?

Comment: I'm having the same problem, any solution yet ?

Comment: What device are you running your app on? Is it an emulator? Do you mind sharing the ABI (arm64 or x86)? Also if you can find the part in logcat that contains the [crash dump](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/debug#debuggerd), that would be very helpful. Thanks!

Comment: I have some problems with ExoPlayer, maybe it is related to some memory leaks with using the player?